# is it possible to load asp:controls through AJAX requests and handle with webservices?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, user-controls

I wanted to make sure it was possible before i do it.  WHat i am going to do is build a treeView which will be passed to the client machine with an ajax call.   The client will be able to sort through the treeview, which will make server requests.  The server requests will be handled clientside through "OnClick ping a webserver with some parameters"

I figured it was doable, i wasnt sure who has really tried this, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call will re-render an UpdatePanel. You can do whatever you want with the contents of that UpdatePanel, including adding treeviews to it, or modifying existing treeviews. In short, yes.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but there might be some things wrong with that, such as connecting the markup that was pulled to its associated server for further updates, or should i just plan something?

Comment: If I'm understanding your comment correctly, you want to make sure that after the postback, the UpdatePanel still has whatever controls, etc. were in it, as specified by the .aspx, when you initially rendered it?  All that's taken care of by the ASP.Net page lifecycle. A postback, AJAX or otherwise, performs the whole page lifecycle all over again, so all the controls are re-rendered, plus whatever changes you make in your postback event handler. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: What about nesting a page within a page?  SOrt of like:  Page A has this backend but the contents of this Div (B) will have server controls referencing elsewhere.  Goal:  AJAX a RatTreeVIew into my target page, and continue to update it as normal.  SOunds darn near impossible, if not impossible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RatTreeView, but anything that derives from System.Web.UI.Control (hence from System.Web.UI.Page) goes through the ASP.Net lifecycle. I don't see an issue with keeping any control constantly updated with AJAX. Perhaps try it, and if you get stuck, a more specific question would get you a more specific answer :)